# How to reopen the inherit after I close it in TFS 2012

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

In TFS 2012, when I close the inherit option of a folder in the tfs web access

http://tfsdemo.com:8080/tfs/Platform/Test1/_versionControl#path=%24%2FTest1%2FT1&_a=contents

I cannot reopen the inherit and I cannot visit the security page, the page said that:

TF14098: Access Denied: User mike needs AdminProjectRights permission(s) for $/Test1/T1/

How to reopen the inherit after I close inherit?

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue - I am project administrator and not a project collection administrator. I haven't found a way to restore the flag. What did you do in the end? Ultimately, I can delete the parent folder and add it back.

Comment: I was made member of the project collection administrators group and I was able to see the folders and set the Inheritance flag back to on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% on exactly what is happening, but if you're saying that you've removed the inherited permissions from T1, then what's probably happened is that rights were probably setup at the Test1 level, and the T1 level was inheriting them giving you access, so once you remove the inherited permissions from Test1, you can no longer access T1 as it's only the default users/permissions.

I'm guessing you're not a project administrator (if so you would have rights)?  I'd check your Project Administrator or Project Collection Administrator groups and get someone to set the permissions back.

Comment: When the user has the project administrator permission, he can reopen the inherit option now. Thank you very much.

Comment: It is the project collection administrators permission.

Comment: Either will have carte blanche on the project, so would be fine.